# C# для новичков

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Подскажите руководство для сборки программных средств для попыток разработки приложений C#.
Или допустим установка Visual Studio, что должно входить чего именно хватит для C#, не хочу ставить лишнее.

Плюс когда ставил Visual Studio pro, не понял как адекватно поставить MSSQL сервер, постоянно вылетали всякие регистрация, активации и т.д. 
Вообщем знатоки, обращаюсь к вам. Очень хочу чтобы вы помогли мне, и пошагово максимально доходчиво расписали.

Опыт в программировании у меня 3 года PHP/MySQL.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы только начинаете работу с C#, то Вам будет достаточно Visual C# Express. Установка очень простая:

- загрузить софт со [страницы](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) загрузки;
- установить компоненты по умолчанию.

После этого ознакомиться с [введением](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y2y4fsy2(v=vs.90).aspx) в работу с Visual C# Express.

Регистрация для Express не обязательна в течение месяца (если не ошибаюсь). Плюс, можно иметь в виду, что для сборки приложений на C# Visual Studio не необходим, достаточно иметь .NET Framework: там есть компилятор и все нужное.

Comment: SQL сервер тоже будет необходим? Его нужно будет отдельно, или он в компонентах будет?

Comment: Перед началом установки будет опция на выбор: устанавливать или не устанавливать SQL сервер.